# Azure Budget ARM template deployment unauthorized

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-rm-template, unauthorized

I am trying to deploy an ARM template containing an Azure budget. Currently I'm using the Azure CLI but it happens via the portal also.

```
az deployment group create --resource-group my-rg --template-file c:\dev\arm_template.json
```

I would like to know what the solution is to avoid the following error:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 10cfac68-3ce9-4527-bee8-df48a761f965. {

  "error": {

    "code": "401",

    "message": "Unauthorized. Request ID: 4c5ee5cb-4b71-4c8b-8965-f3b89cdd2c8a"

  }

}
```

Comment: What permissions do you have? For Azure EA subscriptions, you must have read access to view budgets. To create and manage budgets, you must have contributor permission.

Comment: Owner – Can create, modify, or delete budgets for a subscription.
Contributor and Cost Management contributor – Can create, modify, or delete their own budgets. Can modify the budget amount for budgets created by others.
Reader and Cost Management reader – Can view budgets that they have permission to.

Comment: I do have Contributor access as I can create other resources without a problem

Comment: Verify that you are contributor on the scope you are trying to create a budget. E.g. if you are trying to create a budget on subscription level then you need to be contributor at the subscription level. You being able to create resources doesnt necessarily mean you are a contributor.

Comment: What if i want to create budget on the subscription level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, ended up being the filter, if the filter is not set correctly, then the budget tries to apply to your subscription and not just the resource group or whatever you are targeting

```
{
  "name": "[variables('budgetName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/budgets",
  "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
  "properties": {
    "timePeriod": {
      "startDate": "2020-09-01T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2028-07-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "timeGrain": "Monthly",
    "amount": 40,
    "currentSpend": null,
    "category": "Cost",
    "notifications": {
      "GreaterThan80": {
        "enabled": true,
        "operator": "GreaterThan",
        "threshold": 80,
        "contactEmails": [],
        "contactRoles": [],
        "contactGroups": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups',variables('actionGroupName'))]"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "dimensions": {
        "name": "ResourceGroupName",
        "operator": "In",
        "values": [ "variables('resourceGroup')" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it wasn't using the filter correctly.

Comment: What if i want to create budget on the subscription level?

Comment: You should be able to just leave out the filter then, I needed to add the filter to stop it from going to subscription level

Comment: What if i want to create budget on the subscription level  - For this no need to set the filter property.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. The solution was to use the full ID of the `Action Group` and not just the name.

Example of the notifications part of the ARM template:

```
"notifications": {
  "Notification1": {
    "enabled": true,
    ...
    "contactGroups": [
      "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/ag-name"
    ]
  }
}
```